# difficulty deploying on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can I have a complete guide to deploy an mvc wesite on iis7.0 please.

I am trying to deploy my mvc website on iis 7.0 but I am having the error

### > Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

Line 42: 
Line 43:   
Line 44:     
Line 45:       
Line 46:

Source File: D:\time\web.config    Line: 44

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your app has an application pool configured that runs on .NET Framework 4.0.

To do that select your website and click on Basic Settings... in the Actions menu to the right. This will open a window that let's you choose an application pool.

[image: app pool]

Comment: Good Point, .net 4 has to be installed, but also the app pool has to be configured for it.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC3 requires the .NET framework 4.0

MVC 2 would run on .NET 3.5 (which uses 2.0 CLR), but MVC 3 requires .NET 4.  No other solution than to install .NET 4 on your server.